# get results of query using prepared statements mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I would like to get the results of a query using prepared statements but I don't get anything.

The problem is I'm not able to fetch my results. Can some one show an example how to get results of query using prepared statements?

Here is my code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT `username` FROM `usrs` WHERE `username` = ? ";
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    if (!statement)
    {
        throw new Exception($statement->error);
    }

    $statement->bind_param("s",$username);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($user);
    while ($statement->fetch()) 
    {
        printf("%s", $user);
    }
```

Comment: is the users table spelled "usrs" or "users"?

Comment: it is spelled usrs

Comment: where is $username declared in your bind_param statement?

Comment: actually this a function and $username is passed to it. I check and I am sure it is passed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty close.  I added two lines.  One line stores the result and the other is a check to make sure you had a response from the query.  Run it and see if it helps.

```
$sql = "SELECT `username` FROM `usrs` WHERE `username` = ? ";
  $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

  if (!statement)
  {
      throw new Exception($statement->error);
  }

  $statement->bind_param("s",$username);
  $statement->execute();
  $statement->store_result(); //<-- Added this.
  if($statement->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');//<--Test to see if you have a result.
  $statement->bind_result($user);
  while ($statement->fetch()) 
  {
      printf("%s", $user);
  }
```

Comment: thanks. I get No rows, Although I am sure that the I have data in my database with the corresponding values, but at least now I know where is the error